# Unknown Error, no Error or Crash. C# program on secondary PC

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote a custom calculator specifically for a online game (Path of Exile), on the following system.

Windows 7 Home Premium,
Service Pack 1,
64bit OS

using

Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop,
Release Build, Any CPU

The .exe file copied to c:\ drive, and run by double-clicking the program exe file.  This works just fine on my PC that I wrote the program on.

However when I copy the program over to a secondary PC and run it from that PC it doesn't look right.  The Custom Textboxes created are mis-aligned from where they should be.

I used code from the following thread, to create the textboxes with:

[Textbox not clickable but editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943088/textbox-not-clickable-but-editable/24943375#24943375)

```
public partial class TextBoxMod : TextBox
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        int msg = m.Msg;
        if (msg == (int)WindowsMessage.WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            // messagebox here
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

and in the constructer I called on a method to initialize the textboxes with some basic info like so:

```
// txtBoxPDMin
box.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(155, 191);
box.Name = "txtBoxPDMin";
box.TabIndex = 0;
box.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
box.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(txtBoxKeyMove_KeyDown);
boxes.Add(box);
```

and after the last textbox:

```
foreach (TextBoxMod mod in boxes)
{
    mod.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 22);
    if (mod.Name == "txtBoxAttSpd")
        mod.Text = "0.00";
    else
        mod.Text = "0";

    mod.ForeColor = Color.PaleTurquoise;
    mod.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
    mod.Enter += new System.EventHandler(txtBoxMods_Enter);

    this.Controls.Add(mod);
}
```

I have an image file that shows a picture of what the program looks like on both computers and you can definitely see the difference:

in this Image the left side shows an example of the program running on my Primary PC where I did the actual programming, it is not running in Debug mode this was built then copied to a separated folder where it was run.  The Image on the Right side is what it looks like on my Secondary PC as you can see the Custom Textboxes are mis-aligned and some are not even showing on the form.

[image: Multi-PC Error on Second PC]

So my question is What could be causing this problem?  There are no Errors or Crashes.

Any help is Appreciated...

roadmaster

** Edit **

```
    private void InitializeTextBoxes()
    {
        boxes = new List<TextBoxMod>();
        box = new TextBoxMod();

        // txtBoxPDMin
        box.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left));
        box.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(155, 191);
        box.Name = "txtBoxPDMin";
        box.TabIndex = 0;
        box.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
        box.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(txtBoxKeyMove_KeyDown);
        boxes.Add(box);

        box = new TextBoxMod();

        // txtBoxPDMax
        box.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(220, 191);
        box.Name = "txtBoxPDMax";
        box.TabIndex = 1;
        box.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
        box.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(txtBoxKeyMove_KeyDown);
        boxes.Add(box);

        box = new TextBoxMod();

        // txtBoxFDMin
        box.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(155, 219);
        box.Name = "txtBoxFDMin";
        box.TabIndex = 2;
        box.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
        box.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(txtBoxKeyMove_KeyDown);
        boxes.Add(box);

        box = new TextBoxMod();

        // txtBoxFDMax
        box.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(220, 219);
        box.Name = "txtBoxFDMax";
        box.TabIndex = 3;
        box.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
        box.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(txtBoxKeyMove_KeyDown);
        boxes.Add(box);

        box = new TextBoxMod();

        // txtBoxLDMin
        box.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(155, 247);
        box.Name = "txtBoxLDMin";
        box.TabIndex = 4;
        box.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
        box.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(txtBoxKeyMove_KeyDown);
        boxes.Add(box);

        box = new TextBoxMod();

        // txtBoxLDMax
        box.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(220, 247);
        box.Name = "txtBoxLDMax";
        box.TabIndex = 5;
        box.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
        box.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(txtBoxKeyMove_KeyDown);
        boxes.Add(box);

        box = new TextBoxMod();

        // txtBoxCDMin
        box.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(155, 275);
        box.Name = "txtBoxCDMin";
        box.TabIndex = 6;
        box.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
        box.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(txtBoxKeyMove_KeyDown);
        boxes.Add(box);

        box = new TextBoxMod();

        // txtBoxCDMax
        box.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(220, 275);
        box.Name = "txtBoxCDMax";
        box.TabIndex = 7;
        box.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
        box.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(txtBoxKeyMove_KeyDown);
        boxes.Add(box);

        box = new TextBoxMod();

        // txtBoxAttSpd
        box.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(155, 303);
        box.Name = "txtBoxAttSpd";
        box.TabIndex = 8;
        box.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
        box.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(txtBoxAttSpd_KeyDown);
        boxes.Add(box);

        foreach (TextBoxMod mod in boxes)
        {
            mod.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 22);
            if (mod.Name == "txtBoxAttSpd")
                mod.Text = "0.00";
            else
                mod.Text = "0";

            mod.ForeColor = Color.PaleTurquoise;
            mod.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
            mod.Enter += new System.EventHandler(txtBoxMods_Enter);
            //box.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(txtBoxKeyMove_KeyDown);
            this.Controls.Add(mod);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that sets the X,Y location of each TextBoxMod?

Comment: Nothing in the code stands out.  Your labels look like they are in the correct position.  Are the labels and text boxes separate controls?  Are you using AutoScale and Scale?  If so, make sure they match.

Comment: yes the labels and the textboxes are separate controls, and I don't know what you're referring to with AutoScale and Scale, I don't see them as properties in the VS IDE Properties for either a TextBox or a Label Control, so my guess is that im not using either.

Comment: AutoScaleMode and AutoScaleDimensions are properties on a container control.  You might want to search all cs files for "AutoScale".  These properties adjust control sizes based on the dpi of the system.  So that might explain why it appears different on different computers.

Comment: Ahh, well I found AutoScaleMode on the Form and its set to Font, since the TextBoxes are controls on the Form ill try changing it and see what happens.

Comment: @Loathing, Setting the AutoScaleMode to Inherit has fixed the problem on my secondary pc, I'm going to send the program off to my Nephew and see how it works on his pc, thanks for your help.